# Cannot Log in to Django Admin Interface with Heroku Deployed App

Tags: python, django, heroku

Kind of a strange question, but I cannot login to my admin interface with a Heroku deployed Django app. Whenever I enter in the correct credentials, I get an error stating `Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.` I can authenticate locally in the shell, and when I am running a simple local django server, but not while on the heroku deployed version. Any ideas why? Here is my `settings.py` file. It was automatically generated with the Heroku configured template, ran with this command `$ django-admin startproject --template=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template/archive/master.zip --name=Procfile  myproject`

settings.py

```
import os
import dj_database_url

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pepfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = (
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pepfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = (
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
)

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: Have you created a user in the production site?

Comment: Also, you must not use sqlite on Heroku.

Comment: @DanielRoseman could you please clarify 'production site'. Sorry, but I am very new to heroku.

Comment: Did you create a user on the Heroku version of the site? If so, how?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't believe I have. Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I figured it out. `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser`. Like I said, I'm relatively new to Heroku. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 12):

I faced the similar problem. Then I created a superuser by running:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Then:

```
$ git push -f heroku master
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

It worked all fine.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

`heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser -a <app_name>`

After creating the superuser, refresh your app
& make sure to use a first capital letter in the username section like "Raj" instead of "raj".

Edit:-
Added the -a flag in front of <app_name>, without which heroku will throw an error

Comment: This works even if you keep sqlite as database. I noticed something was off when I tried to change password using 'heroku run python manage.py changepassword' and it said user does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I am facing similar error, but however I have noticed few things in your settings.py I feel should be changed, when you are migrating to heroku the default database needs to be changed to postgresql like this

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

You will find these credentials in your Heroku App's Resources tab->add-ons->postgresql->view credentials.

Refer to these links for detailed information:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES

This link tells you how to separate local_settings from settings:
https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/heroku/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone else. 
After some thorough search on the net, I had still the issue and could not login into the admin page in production.
Therefore , I had to come up with a workaround.
I created a new user in my local environment (checked if I could log in with it on localhost, and it worked), copied the sqlite file located in the app folder,which is called db.sqlite3 , and copied it onto the production server in the same location.
Restarted the app, and i was able to login.
I came up with this after i saw on the command line that the user i just created did not exist.

```
heroku run python /app/src/manage.py changepassword  -a appname
```

which returned:

```
CommandError: user 'yourusername' does not exist
```

Comment: How did you copy the sqlite file to server?

Comment: My app deployment is handled with GitHub, so I took that local .sqlite3 file and uploaded it to the repository.